# Find length of subvectors in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

Given the following vector:

```
signal <- c(0011100110)
```

I would like to find a way to compute the average signal length. Here the fist signal has length 3 (111) and the second signal has length 2. However I can't figure out a good way to subset the original vector into subvectors that would only contain 1s, so that I can compute their average length.

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate posted above but this has definitely been answered before. Look at 1) `strsplit` and 2) `rle`. Oh alright... `rle( strsplit( as.character(signal) , "" )[[1]] )` should be ample to start you off.

Comment: note that `0011100110 == 11100110` (it's not a number in bin base)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach to find the average signal length:

```
signal <- 0011100110

mean(nchar(strsplit(as.character(signal), "0+")[[1]]))
# [1] 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `match.length` attribute of `gregexpr`:

```
mean(attr(gregexpr('1+', signal)[[1]],"match.length"))
[1] 2.5
```